# Effect/bias of believing what you read about other fields despite misreporting of things in your own

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm finding it difficult to phrase this, but I'm sure there's a "law" or bias which says that we'll believe what we read in newspapers and so on about other fields despite reading bad reporting about our own field.

Anyone know what I mean?

Comment: Besides who misreporting things in your own?

Comment: @Lambie I think it refers to things like mainstream news reporting.

Comment: Sounds like you're a state of [_congnitive dissonance_](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/basics/cognitive-dissonance); your behavior (believing what you read) is in conflict with your ideas or knowledge (about less-than-trustworthy reporting)

Comment: You're being unclear.  *Cognitive dissonance*, as mentioned by Gnawme, refers to not believing stuff which conflicts with your own preconceptions.  (It doesn't make much difference whether the conflicting "reporting" is "good" or "bad" in terms of accuracy.)  I'm not aware of any term for believing other stuff about other fields to be "good" even when we "know" that reporting in our own field is "bad".

Comment: One of the answers to that duplicate question refers to the [Gell-Mann Amnesia Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_amnesia_effect)

Comment: @JamesRandom That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**don't believe everything you read**

[Why You Believe Most Everything You Read or Watch on TV](https://lifehacker.com/5953837/why-you-believe-most-everything-you-read-or-watch-on-tv) (a psychology article). One article's take on this subject:

> So, what happens within our minds and emotions that make us receptive
>   to lies, and then resistant to information that exposes the truth? A
>   study led by Stephan Lewandowsky of the University of Western
>   Australia explains part of what may happen. The researchers found that
>   "Weighing the plausibility and the source of a message is cognitively
>   more difficult than simply accepting that the message is true — it
>   requires additional motivational and cognitive resources."

You have cognitive skills in your own field and can possibly filter such 'news'.  In other fields it to too much work to discern the truth ... your mind more easily accepts the 'news' as true.